# Why Android Studio icon in windows taskbar automatically changes?

Tags: android-studio, windows-10

When I installed Android Studio in my Windows 10 pc, then icon for Android Studio used to be this :

[image]

But after a few days, icon has changed itself into this :

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your taskbar, right click -> `Properties` -> Untick `Use small taskbar icons`. (With similar meaning, I don't know the exact original text in English).

The icon file of Android Studio, `$ANDROID_STUDIO/bin/studio.ico`, is an icon file containing 6 pictures, using the size of visible area to decide which one to use. Asking the taskbar NOT to use small icon will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. in windows 10 it's, taskbar right click -> Taskbar Settings -> (Uncheck) Use small taskbar buttons

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed, just delete the studio.ico file and it will work.